# InstantiationException when calling action using struts1-plugin

Tags: struts2, struts

We migrating our old Struts 1 Application to Struts 2 using the struts1-plugin to wrap our actions.
This worked great with some actions but others throw the error shown below:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException 
sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:158)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:189)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:178)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.resolveModel(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:106)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:136)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
de.dak.intranet.webtier.extranet.StartPageFilter.doFilter(StartPageFilter.java:74)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
de.dak.intranet.webtier.auth.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:288)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The configuration for this action very straightforward:

```
<package name="extranet" extends="struts1-default" namespace="/extranet">
  <action name="acceptConditions" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action>
    <param name="className">de.intranet.webtier.extranet.AcceptConditionsAction</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="struts1Stack"/>
    <result name="success">/servlet/index.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

I tried removing the interceptors in the action but that did not change anything.
The action class looks like this (actual logic was omitted):

```
public class AcceptConditionsAction extends Action {
  public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, 
                               ActionForm form, 
                               HttpServletRequest request, 
                               HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws Exception {
    return mapping.findForward("success");
  }
}
```

The link in our jsp template is build correctly with the s:action-tag and another action on the same site works perfectly when the link is clicked. This action however generates the stacktrace shown above and I cannot figure out where it is coming from or how to fix it. The breakpoint inside the action is never reached therefore the error has to occur while instantiating the action itself.

I hope somebody can help me figure out what is happening.

EDIT:
Working action for clarification:

```
<package name="extranet" extends="struts1-default" namespace="/extranet">
  <interceptors>
    <interceptor name="pwdForm" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor>
      <param name="className">de.intranet.webtier.extranet.PasswordForm</param>
      <param name="name">pwdForm</param>
    </interceptor>
  </interceptors>
  <action name="editPassword" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action">
    <param name="className">de.intranet.webtier.extranet.EditPasswordAction</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="pwdForm"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="struts1Stack"/>
    <result name="changePassword">/extranet/changePassword.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

Java implementation looks like the AcceptConditionsAction. Only the execute-method was overwritten and no constructor defined.

Comment: Can you show working action? Do you have some constructor in NOT working actions?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-1-plugin.html#Struts1Plugin-Usage ?

Comment: I will edit my post in a minute with the working action but there is no constructor either action.
I saw the Plugin-Usage site and used it to the best of my knowledge otherwise the other action would not work either.

Comment: You don't have `ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor` in NOT working action.

Comment: That was actually intentional because I don't need a FormBean in this action. Do I have to define an empty or standard interceptor instead?

Comment: You can try with same conf as for the working action to see if the problem is in the form or not.

Comment: Ok, so I figured it out with your advice. Adding the Form worked which made me wonder why.
The struts1Stack adds a lot of interceptors which seem to require a FormBean (like "scopedModelDriven" and "modelDriven"). I deleted the interceptor-ref in my action and only added the interceptors that do not require a model and now it works fine.
Thanks for the help Aleksandr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aleksandr pointed me to the answer:
The interceptor stack provided by the struts1-plugin (called `struts1Stack`) creates several interceptors that require a Form (i.e. `scopedModelDriven`, `modelDriven` and some others). If you don't use the entire stack and only add the interceptors needed by the action, it is not necessary anymore to define a `FormBean`.

Answer (score 0):

remove interceptor-ref "strutsStack", add "staticParams" will do the trick.
as shown in below

```
<package name="extranet" extends="struts1-default" namespace="/extranet">
  <action name="acceptConditions" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action>
    <param name="className">de.intranet.webtier.extranet.AcceptConditionsAction</param>
    <!--interceptor-ref name="struts1Stack"/-->
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <result name="success">/servlet/index.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```